# Cant solve the didSelectRowAtIndexPath not firing issue - ios

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, didselectrowatindexpath

I have created one  `commonViewcontroller` class for accessing it's view from all tabs and other `viewcontrollers`, and the `commonViewcontroller` class is instantiated from `Appdelegate`as shown:

```
 - (void) createCommonView   // Instantiating 
{
    if (commonVC == nil)
     {
        commonVC = [[commonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"commonViewController" bundle:nil];
     }
        [self.window addSubview:commonVC.view];
}

-(void)hidePopupView  //Hiding common view
{
    [Utility animateUIViewWhenFrameChanged:menuVC.view newFrame:CGRectMake(0, -500, 188, 500) animationDuration:.8 animationDelay:0];
}

-(void)showPopupView    //Showing common view
{                       
    [Utility animateUIViewWhenFrameChanged:menuVC.view newFrame:CGRectMake(0, 540, 188, 500) animationDuration:.8 animationDelay:0];
}
```

also view's show&hide method is defined in `Appdelegate` as shown above and i have called the instantiating and showing methods in `Appdelegate` from other `viewcontroller` classes as shown.

```
 AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        [appDel createView];
        [appDel showPopupView];
```

and it shows fine, except the `tableview` in `commonViewControllers` view, its `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` not firing! All other delegate methods are firing perfectly, and i have tried many of the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`  not firing solutions in Stack. None helped, guys please help! iam really got stuck with this issue. Thanks.

> UPDATE: I have tried these all for my tableView:

```
self.popUpTableView.scrollEnabled                = YES;
self.popUpTableView.allowsSelection              = YES;
self.popUpTableView.delegate                     = self;
self.popUpTableView.dataSource                   = self;
self.popUpTableView.userInteractionEnabled       = YES;
self.popUpTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

Comment: Is "self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled" = true?. Are you sure it is didSelectRowAtIndexPath not didDeselectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @KrisJulio: its all ok, i have checked it so many times.

Comment: Is the tableview created programmatically or in nib/mainstoryboard. If it is possible that the tableview is duplicated, you can check what tableview is calling the delegate method by adding tags. Or it is also possible that the commonViewController view eat the touch events.

Comment: @KrisJulio it s created via xib, and its delegates are connected. how can i check commonViewController view eat the touch events?

Comment: I think there's no issue on eating touch events. Did you change "Selection: to "No Selection" on tableview properties

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84686/discussion-between-mvp-and-kris-julio).